# To prove $\int_0^1 \frac{\ f(x)-f(0)}{x^α}dx$ converges

Tags: real-analysis, integration, improper-integrals

Let $f(x)$ be real valued $C^1$ function and $α$ be real number and $1<α<2$.
I want to prove $\int_0^1 \frac{\ f(x)-f(0)}{x^α}dx$ converges.

My try: Using mean value theorem, I could prove there exists some $C>0$, such that for arbitrary $x \in [0,1]$, $|f(x)-f(0)| \le C|x|$ holds.

But from here, I cannot proceed.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: You are mssing some crucial hypothesis. The statement is certainlty false if $f$ us just some real valued function.

Comment: Sorry, $f$ is supposed to be $C^1$.

Comment: Using your estimate $$
\int_0^1 {\frac{{f(x) - f(0)}}{{x^\alpha  }}dx}  \le C\int_0^1 {x^{1 - \alpha } dx}  = \frac{1}{{2 - \alpha }} < +\infty.
$$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By [Taylor's Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor%27s_theorem#Taylor%27s_theorem_in_one_real_variable), we have

$$f(x)=f(0)+h(x)x$$

where

$$\lim_{x\to0}h(x)=0$$

Thus, $h(x)$ is bounded by $1$ in some $\delta$ neighborhood of $0$. This implies

$$\int_0^1\frac{f(x)-f(0)}{x^\alpha}dx=\int_0^\delta\frac{f(x)-f(0)}{x^\alpha}dx+\int_\delta^1\frac{f(x)-f(0)}{x^\alpha}dx$$

The second integral obviously converges while for the first integral

$$\int_0^\delta\frac{f(x)-f(0)}{x^\alpha}dx=\int_0^\delta\frac{f(0)+h(x)x-f(0)}{x^\alpha}dx=\int_0^\delta\frac{h(x)x}{x^\alpha}dx$$

$$\leq \int_0^\delta\frac{|h(x)|}{x^{\alpha-1}}dx\leq \int_0^\delta\frac{1}{x^{\alpha-1}}dx=\frac{\delta^{2-\alpha}}{2-\alpha}$$

Comment: You computed the last integral incorrectly.

Comment: Whoops, looks like I forgot the $-1$ when I computed it